# Finite difference code for 2D and 3D arrays using CuPy ElementwiseKernel

Tags: python, cupy, finite-difference

I am trying to write a finite difference Python code for 2D and 3D arrays using CuPy library. I want to use cupy.ElementwiseKernel() to speed up my code. Currently, I am facing problems to write the ElementwiseKernel for 2D array where I want to take the central difference similar to slicing. I have the following code where I want to keep the slicing inside the kernel itself.

```
device = 'CPU'
device_rank = 0

if device == 'CPU':
    import numpy as ncp
    from numpy import copy
    
else:
    import cupy as ncp
    from cupy import copy

    dev = ncp.cuda.Device(device_rank)
    dev.use()

import time

Nx = 16000
Ny = 16000

Lx = 2*ncp.pi
Ly = 2*ncp.pi

dx = Lx/Nx
dy = Ly/Ny

X = ncp.linspace(0,Lx,Nx+1)
Y = ncp.linspace(0,Ly,Ny+1)

X_mesh, Y_mesh = ncp.meshgrid(X,Y,indexing='ij')

temp = ncp.zeros([Nx+1,Ny+1])

def dfx(f, d_type):
    # Central difference of array 'f' w.r.t. x
    # For peridoic f
    if d_type == 0:
        if device == 'GPU':
            temp1 = f[2:,:]
            temp2 = f[:-2,:]
            derv_kernel = ncp.ElementwiseKernel(
                'T temp1, T temp2, T dx',
                'T derv',
                '''
                derv = (temp1 - temp2)/(2*dx);
                ''',
                'derv_kernel'
                )
            derv_kernel(temp1,temp2,dx,temp[1:-1,:])
        
        elif device == 'CPU':
            temp[1:-1,:] = (f[2:,:] - f[:-2,:])/(2*dx)
        # Boundary terms when f is periodic in x
        temp[0,:] = (f[1,:] - f[-2,:])/(2*dx)
        temp[-1,:] = copy(temp[0,:])
    return temp

A = ncp.sin(X_mesh)
B = dfx(A, 0)

print('Max error in derivative: ', ncp.max(ncp.cos(X_mesh)-B))

if device == 'GPU':
    ncp.cuda.runtime.deviceSynchronize()
t1 = time.time()

for i in range(10):
    dfx(A,0)
    A += 2*ncp.pi

if device == 'GPU':
    ncp.cuda.runtime.deviceSynchronize()
t2 = time.time()

print('time = ', t2-t1)
```

I also tried using `raw T f` where we can take `i` index but I am having problems to use it for 2D array where we need two indices. Any help would be great since I can generalize it for my solver. I am not acquainted with CUDA.

```
derv_kernel = ncp.ElementwiseKernel(
                'raw T f, float64 dx',
                'T derv',
                '''
                for(int i = 0; i < Nx+1; ++i){
                    for(int j = 0; j < Ny+1; ++i){
                        derv = (f[i + 1,j] - f[i - 1,j]) / (2*dx);
                    } 
                }
                ''',
                'derv_kernel'
                )
            derv_kernel(f,dx,temp)
```